# "HTTP 404 Not Found" trying to launch simple phpinfo.php

Tags: javascript, php, sql, iis, charts

I'm attempting to install php on my Win 7 laptop machine. I am getting an "HTTP 404 Not Found" when I enter localhost/phpinfo.php. I have so far done the following steps.

1. Downloaded and installed VC11 x86 Thread Safe (2015-Feb-19 01:45:25) into my C:\php folder from http://windows.php.net/download#php-5.6.
2. Copied and renamed the php.ini-development file to php.ini and edited and saved the new php.ini file modifiying the "user_dir =" to "user_dir = C:\php.
3. Enabled all IIS stuff in "programs and features".
4. Inside IIS I have "added Module Mapping.." under Handler Mappings with
    Request path: C:\php,
    Module: FastCgiModule,
    Executable (optional): C:\php\php-cgi.exe,
    and Name: FastCGIJay
5. Also inside IIS under Default Documents I have added:
    Index.php and 
    Default.php
6. I have added ;C:\php on the end of my environment variables string.
7. I have restarted IIS service and rebooted.

I have another older pc I have done the same steps and have it working(I can see the phpinfo page when entering //localhost/phpinfo.php). I have even deleted the entire setup on that pc and have installed php using the installer from microsoft and it works fine. I did this because the installer wouldn't work on this laptop.

I need it working on this laptop because I am logging data to SQL Server 2014 express and I eventually want to chart my data to a website through javascript and I've read that using SQL connection strings in javascript is not secure.

I don't know if it matters but I have a .NET web service running in C:\websites that receives get request from a wifi enabled microcontroller. The web service passes the data through a stored procedure in the .NET webservice to SQL at 10 second intervals. I have configured this service in Default Web Site in IIS.

What is it I'm missing here? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If this "http-404-not-found" coming when running http://localhost/phpinfo.php, try checking that where the `phpinfo.php` file is located. If you are using Linux then check if using ls in cd /var/www giving you index.html or not.
If it's a folder html then create the `phpinfo.php` file inside that html folder.

**Picture of my linux terminal:**

[image]

1. open Linux terminal
2. write `cd /var/www`
3. type the `ls` command in the terminal and see the result. If you are getting `index.html` then you can create and write the `phpinfo.php` there only by `sudo nano phpinfo.php`. And write `<?php phpinfo() ?>` inside it,press ctrl+ o, hit enter and then `ctrl+x`. Then `http://localhost/phpinfo.php` should be working.
   Else if you are getting `html` folder when using `ls` command inside`/var/www` then you should get inside the `html` folder using `cd html`. Now using `ls` you will see an `index.html` file. Now here you can create a `phpinfo.php` file as said above and try running `http://localhost/phpinfo.php`, It will work.

Comment: The person is using a windows computer not a Linux computer so please make references to the appropriate windows commands as well, thanx

Answer (score 0):

You must close your IIS server running for .NET otherwise it wont work. As both are using port :80.

Comment: Interesting, so how is data typically pulled into a website from SQL Server using Visual Studio 2013 Express and php? All I really want is to chart logged SQL data to my website. I'd like to have charting features like pan, zoom, and possibly live data as it comes in. Java script, Ajax, or jQuery allows the charting features but I'll need php to pull the data securely. I still want to log all the while too.

Comment: You can set different port ,in that case it will work simultaneously.

Comment: I have changed my "default Web Site" port to 81 by right clicking and edit bindings. I changed my microcontroller to communicate to port 81. And I have changed my router settings "Internal Start Port" to 81 and External Start Port to 81. localhost/phpinfo.php does not show in my browser and my microcontroller has stopped communicating as well. Maybe I don't understand if I've taken the correct steps.

Comment: you two port using 81 . Better change someone 81 then some one 82 do you have this file in www or htdocs folder phpinfo.php?

Comment: I don't understand what you're typing sorry. For testing I actually have the phpinfo.php file in both C:\inetpub\wwwroot and my .net site C:\websites.